# Multi-hop X forwarding via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

Now I have such a need:
Xshell——host A——host B
When I ssh directly from Xshell to **host B**, I can open xclock
When I ssh from Xshell to **host A**, and then connect to **host B** via **host A**, opening xclock will fail with an error

```
[root @ vs-6 ~] # xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

Adding the **-Y** parameter when using ssh on **host A** should solve the problem, but it should also require other configuration or program support.
What should I do to achieve **Multi-hop X forwarding via ssh**

Note:I think there should be some configuration or parameters that can be modified to solve this problem.because it can be solved on a certain host, but I cannot use root privileges to view the related configuration and parameters of this host

Answer (score 0):

Here's [Reference method](https://serverfault.com/a/425413)
On **host A** (centos7-1908), you only need to install the **xorg-x11-xauth** package.
 Then exit all shells, and then reconnect to **host A**. At this time, the **$DISPLAY** environment variable is automatically generated, and the **-Y** parameter is added when connecting to **host B**. This problem can be solved.